# I want to upload a file to FTP server using C# - Error coming from GetRequestStream()

Tags: c#, ftp, upload

```
        string CurFileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\" + ErrFileName.Trim() + DateTime.Today.ToString("ddMMyyyy").Trim() + ".csv";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string Destination = "ftp://x.xxx.xxx.xxx//xxxxxxxxxx//xxxxxxxx//" + ErrFileName.Trim();
        try
        {
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Destination);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("*******", "*********");
                request.Proxy = null;
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                byte[] fileContents;
                using (StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(CurFileName))
                {
                    fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
                    sourceStream.Close();
                }

                request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
                
                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                    requestStream.Close();
                }

                using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine($"Upload File Complete, status {response.StatusDescription}");
                    response.Close();
                    System.IO.File.Delete(CurFileName);
                }
            
        }
        catch(WebException e)
        {
            String status = ((FtpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription;
            Console.WriteLine(status);
        }
```

Hello everyone, i want to upload a csv file to ftp server.  it is not uploading and also
i am getting error from GetRequestStream() line.  specified file path is wrong
can anyone help me.

thanks in advance

Comment: **What** error are you getting?

Comment: maybe Destination  is wrong, the folder does not exist on ftp yet.

Comment: i found issue in destination path and i corrected it.  So, now it is working.  Thank you for your reply